# PHP MYSQL Similar files

Tags: php, mysql

I need to download similar results. Writing in detail, if I write data from a particular file of the "files" table, I would like to see other files that have the same record "id_tag_main" underneath.

I have tables:

**tags**

```
id  |  name  | 

 1     one  
 2     two 
 3     three
```

**tags_files**

```
id | id_tag | id_file | id_tag_main

 1     1        1          3
 2     -        2          2
 3     -        3          2
 4     -        4          2
```

**files**

```
id |    name   | 

 1     city  
 2     vehicles 
 3     weather   
 4     gifts
```

I need Mysql php query, I try about LEFT JOIN but results is not correct.

If I choose from files "vehicles", then vehicles have `"id_tag_main" = 2` and i want more files where `"id_tag_main" = 2`

Comment: I couldn't understand what you asked for, could you describe more?

Comment: Please provide the desired result.

Comment: If i choose from files "vehicles", then vehicles have "id_tag_main" = 2 and i want more files where "id_tag_main" = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you onl y can choos vehicle from files than you nbedd following query

```
SELECT f.name
FROM tags_files tf INNER JOIN files f ON tf.id_file = f.id
WHERE id_tag_main = (SELECT id_tag_main 
                     FROM tags_files 
                     WHERE id_file = (SELECT id FROM files WHERE name = 'vehicles' ));
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tags_files (
>   `id` int,
>   `id_tag` int,
>   `id_file` int,
>   `id_tag_main` int
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tags_files
>   (`id`, `id_tag`, `id_file`, `id_tag_main`)
> VALUES
>   ('1',     '1',        '1',          '3'),
>   ('2',     NULL,        '2',          '2'),
>   ('3 ',    NULL,        '3',          '2'),
>   ('4',   NULL,        '4',          '2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE files (
>   `id` int,
>   `name` VARCHAR(14)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO files
>   (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1',     'city'),
>   ('2',     'vehicles'),
>   ('3',     'weather'),
>   ('4',     'gifts');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tags (
>   `id` int,
>   `name` VARCHAR(11)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tags
>   (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1',     'one'),
>   ('2',     'two'),
>   ('3',     'three');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT f.name
> FROM tags_files tf INNER JOIN files f ON tf.id_file = f.id
> WHERE id_tag_main = (SELECT id_tag_main 
>                      FROM tags_files 
>                      WHERE id_file = (SELECT id FROM files WHERE name = 'vehicles' ));
> ```
>
> ```
> | name     |
> | :------- |
> | vehicles |
> | weather  |
> | gifts    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=feb8dd818200b7cc4cce7aab47b963c9)*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its this?

```
   select *
   from files as f1
   left join tags_files on tags_files.id_tag_main = f1.id
   left join files as f2 on tags_files.id_file = f2.id
   where f1.name = 'vehicles'
```